# Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':No cached version available for offline mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was already ***activated offline mode*** in the android studio. The main problem is that Project Sync failed.

These are the my **dependencies**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.starcom.practicemp3audio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

These are my **Gradle sync**

```
 Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.

 Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0): No cached version available for offline mode
```

Comment: I think you should be connected to internet and then some gradle files are needed to be downloaded

Comment: Thank you  @Zahra. Yaa you are right but if We remove " -beat1" in error line and sync once problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When I consult to my mentor they simply remove ***-beta1*** from my dependencies

```js
Before 
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
     
After

     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

And **"Sync"** once again problem has been resolved.